# CSS3 media query isn't accesable

Tags: css, media-queries

i have a div with an background image .. i need to give the div margin-bottom in the large screens and to remove the margin in other screens.
but when i inspect in the browser i see that the code in media query isn't readable.

```
<div class="logo FLRight FLNone-xs">
<div>
```

this code is readable in the css file without any meadia

```
.header .nav-container .logo{
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    width: 160px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

and this code isn't readable in the browser ... this is just a simple example .. the case is applied on all classes in my file

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { /*large screens*/

    .header .nav-container .logo{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I read 3 classes in the top example. Which one is it?

Comment: which browser are you using or is it a cross browser issue?

Comment: @scoopzilla .logo class ... but the problem is not about the class .. any class will face the same issue

Comment: @neophyte i tried firefox and chrome with the same failure in both

Answer (score 0):

```css
.logo{
    background: url('http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Logo_Image_01.png') no-repeat;
    width: 160px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { /*large screens*/

    .logo{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body>
    <div class="logo FLRight FLNone-xs">
    <h1>hiiii</h1>
<div>
</body>
  </html>
```

Remove the associated classes from `@media`.
See the above code for reference it is working.
Hope this helps!